# Cyber Ark Spring configuration (With Mule ESB)

Tags: spring, jms, mule, cyber-ark

I am trying to integrate Cyber Ark (security management) with Spring and we use Mule as our ESB

```
<jms:connector 
                        name="jmsConnector"
                        jndiProviderUrl="${tibjmsURL}"
                        connectionFactoryJndiName="${tibjmsConnFactory}"
                        username="${tibjndiUser}" 
                        jndiInitialFactory="${tibjndiInitialFactoryClassName}"                                         
                        specification="1.1"
                        createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true"
                        numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="1"
           >

           <spring:property name="password">
                <ref bean="idsJmsPassword"/>
           </spring:property>
```

I am trying to get my password from the cyber ark and that is injected as a spring bean.Any one done this before? How do i inject a password into the JMS connector (tag show in the code)?Currently it loads it from a property file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your configuration above with Mule 3.1.2 and, provided you fix the ref element to be in the Spring namespace:

```
<spring:ref bean="idsJmsPassword"/>
```

and provided *idsJmsPassword* is actually a String, I confirm *setPassword()* is called on *org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector* with the value of *idsJmsPassword*.

This should then allow you to achieve your goal.